# pandas Timestamp with np.where comparison

Tags: arrays, pandas, timestamp, comparison

Is there a way to find the matching elements of two arrays of timestamps in Python?

I'm trying to do this for two arrays as so:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

xrp[:,0]
Out[135]: 
array([Timestamp('2018-03-08 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-07 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2018-03-06 00:00:00'), ...,
       Timestamp('2013-08-06 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-08-05 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2013-08-04 00:00:00')], dtype=object)

btc[:,0]
Out[136]: 
array([Timestamp('2018-03-08 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-07 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2018-03-06 00:00:00'), ...,
       Timestamp('2013-04-30 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-04-29 00:00:00'),
       Timestamp('2013-04-28 00:00:00')], dtype=object)

val = np.where(btc[:,0]==xrp[:,0])
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.

val
Out[138]: (array([], dtype=int64),)
```

It would seem that np.where and Timestamps aren't very compatible, or used to be but not anymore.

I'd like to do this without loops if possible.

The shapes of each array are:

```
xrp[:,0].shape
Out[139]: (1678,)

btc[:,0].shape
Out[140]: (1776,)
```

Comment: Sure, but print `xrp[:,0].shape` and `btc[:,0].shape` and tell me what they are please.

Comment: Hope that helps, they may need flattening, maybe, given that comma?

Comment: The fact that their shapes are different should imply that an elementwise comparison isn't possible.

Comment: Ah, okay I see, I had a slip in understanding how np.where actually compares the data, thank you!

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with `np.where`, the error is when the a == b expression is computed. Better check where these come from. Good luck!

Comment: @user8188120 you should prepare a [mcve] that demonstrates shorter length arrays.  Keep them unequal lengths to preserve part of the problem.  This way, you can show us what output you expect.  I suspect you want to compare every combination and identify which combinations are equal.  There **is** an answer for that.  But I don't want to waste my time guessing that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and input both, I'll try to make my questions more concise and explanatory in future. @piRSquared that is what I'm looking to do yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `a` and `b` be your arrays

```
i, j = np.where(a == b[:, np.newaxis])

print(a[i])
print(b[j])
```